# Updating one drop down menu according to option selected in another drop down menu from database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, drop-down-menu

**EDITED AFTER SUGGESTIONS (STILL UNRESOLVED):**

I have 2 drop down menu's, one called Country, and the other called City. When the user chooses a country from the Country drop down menu (hereafter a drop down menu will be referred to as a DDM for brevity), I want the City DDM to show all the cities in that particular country.

I have a **relation (called location**) in the database of the following simple form (with some entries):

```
id country city
    1  India  New Delhi
    2  India  Hyderabad
    3   USA    San Diego
    4   USA    Palo Alto
```

This is the code I wrote :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Admin Page</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".country").change(function()
        {
            var country=$(this).val();
            var dataString = 'country='+ country;
            alert(dataString);
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getcity.php",
                data: dataString,
                dataType : html,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data, textStatus)
                {
                    alert(textStatus);
                    $(".city").html(data);
                } 
            });

        });
    });
</script>

<body>

<br />
<legend><h2>Welcome Admin!</h2></legend>


<?php
include('db.php');

$sql="SELECT distinct country FROM location"; 
$result=mysqli_query($con, $sql); 

if (!$result)
{
    echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

echo '<h4>Location :</h4>';
echo '<select name="loaction" class="location">';
echo '<option value="foo">'.'Choose Country'.'</option>';
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<option value='.$row[country].'>'.$row[country].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';

?>

<h4><label>City :</label> </h4>
<select name = 'city' class = 'city'>
    <option value = 'foo' > Choose City </option>
</select>
```

I hope you have taken the trouble to scroll down and see the above code. The file getcity.php is as follows :

```
<?php
include('db.php');

if($_POST['country'])
{
    $country=$_POST['country'];
    $sql=mysql_query("select id, city from location where country='$country'");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $id=$row['id'];
        $city=$row['city'];
        echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$city.'</option>';
    }
}
```

However, I cannot see anything in the City DDM even after the status returned from the AJAX call (seen through alert()) is a 'Success'.

What am I missing?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use JavaScript for sure.
I recommend using jQuery, so you'll handle the event [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) in the countries list, and make it send an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call to the server and grab the result as a json object, for example :

```
{
  'country':{
     'id' :10,
     'name' 'France',
     ...
     'cities':{
        '1':'lille',
        '2':'paris'
        ...

     }
  }
}
```

use [json-encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to encode the result into json object in php,
and use [.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to change the cities in the second list.

```
$(".cities_list").html("<option name='1'>lille</option><option name='2'>france</option> ...");
```

and here is an [example](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'm doing it:

You need two selectors:

```
<select name="state" class="stateSelector" ></select>
<select name="city" class="citySelector" ></select>
```

And a jQuery ajax (get) call, that will fire every time a selector of stateSelector class changes:

```
$('.stateSelector').change(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://site.com/getCities/"+$(this).val()+"/all",{}, function(j){
        var options = '<option value="0">- CITY -</option>';
        for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
            options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].name + '</option>';
        }
        $('.citySelector').html(options);
        $('.citySelector').prop("selectedIndex", 0);
    });
});
```

At the server side, you need to call an url (http://site.com/getCities/{stateId}) that will receive the state id and return a JSON collection with all cities from that particular state, in this example the JSON structure has id (j[i].id) and name (j[i].name).

Comment: Kindly go through my updated code once and tell me where I might be going wrong. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use AJAX for setting the options from database

In your view file:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#yourCountryDropDownID").live("change", function(){
        var country = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "yourSiteUrl/getCities.php/?country="+country,
            success: function(data){
               $("#city_div").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
})
</script>
```

You cities dropdown should be in a div with id `city_div`. now make a PHP file `getCities.php` and put your below code in that.

```
if(isset($_GET["country"]) && !empty($_GET["country"])){
    //Your Code
    //to get cities from country id
    // will come here
}
```

Don't forget to import jQuery in your view.

Comment: Kindly go through my updated code once and tell me where I might be going wrong. Thanks a ton!

Comment: `<div id="city"> <h4><label>City :</label> </h4>
<select name = 'city'>
    <option value = 'foo' > Choose City </option>
</select>
    </div>` Use this.. and also check in firbug console panel what's your ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version of your code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Admin Page</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.country').change(function(){
            $.get("http://172.17.0.2/getcity.php?country="+$(this).val(),{}, function(data){
                $('.city').html(data);
                $('.city').prop("selectedIndex", 0);
            });
        });         
    });
</script>

<body>

<br />
<legend><h2>Welcome Admin!</h2></legend>


<?php

$rows = array( 
                array('country' => 'India'), 
                array('country' => 'Brazil')
            );

echo '<h4>Location :</h4>';
echo '<select name="country" class="country">';
foreach ($rows as  $row)
{
    echo '<option value='.$row['country'].'>'.$row['country'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';

?>

<h4><label>City :</label> </h4>
<select name = 'city' class = 'city'>
    <option value = 'foo' > Choose City </option>
</select>
```

This is the script (getcity.php) ajax will call:

```
<?php
include('db.php');

if($_GET['country'])
{
        $rows = array( 
                array('country' => 'India', 'city' => 'Nova Delhi'), 
                array('country' => 'Brazil', 'city' => 'Rio de Janeiro')
            );

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        if($row['country'] == $_GET['country']) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['city'].'">'.$row['city'].'</option>';
        }
    }
}
```

Do a test in this script in your browser:

```
http://172.17.0.2/cityAjax.php?country=Brazil
```

In Chrome you can just do

```
view-source:http://172.17.0.2/getcity.php?country=Brazil
```

The source source code of this call should be:

```
<option value="Rio de Janeiro">Rio de Janeiro</option>
```

And, of course, you'll have to edit the host ip address 172.17.0.2. :)